# How to Check In Sharepoint Document without Adding Required fields using Web Services?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to **Update a document programatically** where some of **required fields are missing**.(and we need to checkin document before updating)
In order to checkIn document all required fields should be added.

But problem here is that to add those required field i have to again Update the Document :(

**So is there any way:**

1. **To CheckIn Document witout adding required field.** or
2. **To add those required field without using (UpdateList anf UpdateListItem methods of List.asmx)**

Comment: I doubt that the API will let you check in something without the requried fields. Even if it does, I would strongly recommend against it - that's the whole purpose of required fields, and there's a reason why someone designated them as required!

Comment: then is there any way to add those required field.Other than above two methods of Update as they need documnt to be check In before Updating

Comment: please stop adding ": C#" at the end of your titles. Adding a "C#" tag is enough.

Comment: Are you uploading the document before updating??? Or this document already exist and you want to update it?

Answer (score 0):

Required fields are just that, required. So you must put something in them.

If they are string fields, you could just set then to **NA** for Not Available. Then if you have any business logic around this you could identify NA as not being filled out.